# Копирование и вывод HTML блока

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, javascript-events

Обычный многоуровневый список.
**Суть:** Необходимо скопировать список
`<ul class="dropdown__list">` который находится в элементе списка
`<li class="nav__item dropdown">` и вывести вместо `id="main-list"`

По нажатию на кнопку `Назад` возвращать всё обратно,
т.е. нужно хранить `id="main-list"` и выводить обратно по клику.

Элементов `<li class="nav__item dropdown">` и `<ul class="dropdown__list">` будет много в разметке, поэтому нужно прослушивать нажатие на элемент и в нём искать список.

**UPD:**

Добавил jQuery код который есть сейчас, но он немного некорректно работает.
Выводит много ссылок почему-то.

```js
var myList = $('.nav__item.dropdown');
$(myList).on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var find = $(this).find('.dropdown__list');
  var clone = find.children().removeClass('dropdown__item').addClass('nav__item').clone();
  $('.nav__list .nav__item').replaceWith(clone);
});
```

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul>li>a {
  color: blue;
}

ul>li>ul>li>a {
  color: red;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

button:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav__list" id="main-list">
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">Cобытия</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav__item dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">О палате</a>
    <ul class="dropdown__list">
      <li class="dropdown__item">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">
                        Комиссия
                    </a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown__item">
        <a href="##" class="dropdown__link">Нормативно-правовая база</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown__item">
        <a href="###" class="dropdown__link">Структура</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown__item">
        <a href="####" class="dropdown__link">Обратная связь</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown__item">
        <a href="#####  " class="dropdown__link">Кадровая политика</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Взаимодействие</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Контакты</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Фотогалерея</a></li>
</ul>

<button type="button">Назад</button>
```

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, обозначьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый нажатием на `v` под счётчиком голосов

Answer (score 1):

Вы переусложнили себе задачу.

Сделайте отдельный список и держите его скрытым. При клике в основном списке - копируйте нужный кусок основного списка в этот отдельный список и показывайте вместе с кнопкой. А при клике на кнопку - скрывайте и восстанавливайте основной список.

Смотрите пример кода под ниже:

```js
var myList = $('.nav__item.dropdown');
$(myList).on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var find = $(this).find('.dropdown__list');
  var clone = find.children().clone();
  clone.removeClass('dropdown__item').addClass('nav__item');
  $('#selected-list').html(clone);
  $('#selected-list, #main-list, #back-btn').toggle();
});
$('#back-btn').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#selected-list, #main-list, #back-btn').toggle();
});
```

```css
* {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

ul>li>a {
  color: blue;
}

ul>li>ul>li>a {
  color: red;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

button:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav__list" id="main-list">
  <li class="nav__item">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">Cобытия</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav__item dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="nav__link">О палате</a>
    <ul class="dropdown__list">
      <li class="dropdown__item">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown__link">
                        Комиссия
                    </a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown__item">
        <a href="##" class="dropdown__link">Нормативно-правовая база</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown__item">
        <a href="###" class="dropdown__link">Структура</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown__item">
        <a href="####" class="dropdown__link">Обратная связь</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown__item">
        <a href="#####  " class="dropdown__link">Кадровая политика</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Взаимодействие</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Контакты</a></li>
  <li class="nav__item"><a href="#" class="nav__link">Фотогалерея</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav__list hidden" id="selected-list" style="display:none;">
</ul>


<button type="button" id="back-btn" style="display:none;">Назад</button>
```

Comment: такая реализация для 3х уровненного списка подойдет ?

Comment: @ANYWAYCODE Всё зависит от того, как Вы хотите это видеть